# Hierarchical Top-Down Performance Analysis for AMD Processors

Tags: x86, profiling, x86-64, performancecounter, amd-processor

I noticed that the Intel's manual contain something called [Hierarchical Top-Down Performance Characterization Methodology and Locating Performance Bottlenecks](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf). It is a manual that describes how to debug low-level performance issues on your code: is your code slow because the instructions are not decoded, there are I cache misses, L cache misses, overutilization of a single resource in the core etc. The manual tells you exactly what counters you need to read in order to get the high level information. Is there a similar thing for AMD processors?

Comment: Yes, AMD CPUs have HW perf counters.  I think Linux `perf` knows how to use them, so you can simply do that for corresponding events to the ones Intel suggests using.

Comment: I can get using perf infromation about data cache misses, front end stalls and branch prediction misses quite easily. But beckend stalls are very messy because these are architecture specific. Did the stall happend because too many pending loads, too many pending stores or due to instruction dependencies? The problem is that the Intel's manual tells you exactly what registers you need to look at how you should combine them to get the high-level numbers. Not so with AMD :(

Comment: If you have Linux, does `perf list` not document them well?  I'd search for ones with promising names, then read in detail their descriptions to see if they sound like what you're looking for.  (And/or consult AMD's manuals; I assume they're documented somewhere.)

Comment: From what I see, AMD perf counters are messy and there seems to have no official support for TMA from AMD. It means its counters are not grouped well. Can try `perf list metricgroups` to see if any hope.